# Не понимаю выражение return cb(0) if cb else 0

Tags: python-3.x

```
def zero(cb=None): return cb(0) if cb else 0
```

Есть функции, в них есть cb(0) Что делает эта конструкция , конкретно cb(0). Это присваивание или что? Не могу найти информацию, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Происходит вызов функции `cb` с позиционным аргументом `0`.

Comment: В питоне переменной может быть что угодно, в том числе имя функции

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
def zero(cb=None): return cb(0) if cb else 0
```

Данная функция принимает один необязательный именованный аргумент `cb` (со стандартным значением `None`).

Если аргумент `cb` будет передан, то условие `if cb` станет истинно, вследствие чего функция `zero` вернёт результат вызова `cb(0)`.

То есть, в функцию можно передать (а далее вызвать) и другую функцию.